# Custom configuration section for Azure configuration files

Tags: azure

I see that Azure supports basic AppSettings name/value pair style of configuration settings.  However, I can't find any mention that custom configuration settings are also supported.  Are they?

Comment: If you want a completely abstract way to configure application check out this library https://github.com/aloneguid/config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom configuration settings are not supported. See my answer here: [CloudConfigurationManager does not pick up ApplicationSettings from app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611404/cloudconfigurationmanager-does-not-pick-up-applicationsettings-from-app-config/11611651#11611651)